# Error al automatizar la instalación de Postgresql 9.4 en sistema embebido con Debian

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash

necesito instalar Postgresql 9.4 en sistemas embebidos que ejecutan Debian:

```
Linux ICNEXUS-Debian 3.10.53-1.1.0_ga+g496fbe0 #93 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 22 09:18:25 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Tengo un script de bash en el que ejecuto todo lo necesario para instalar las herramientas y configurar el entorno. Con la instrucción: `apt-get install postgresql -y &>> $logFil`  instalo Postgresql 9.4.

El resultado de la instalación se puede ver en el siguiente [log](https://pastebin.com/kxLJe1F6). Como se puede ver en este log, un "fallo" es el siguiente:

```
Creating new cluster 9.4/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.4/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
  locale es_ES.UTF-8
Las banderas de /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main están puestas como ---------------C
```

Después de instalar todos los programas que va ha utilizar el sistema ejecuto la siguiente función:

```
##
## Creación y configuración de la base de datos.
##
setupDataBase(){
    firstInstallation=$1
    logFile=$2
    CREATE_DB="create-user-database-and-schema.sql"
    CREATE_DB_TABLES="create-initial-tables.sql"

    # Esta función solo debería ejecutarse en la primera instalación.
    if [ "$firstInstallation" = true ]; then
        if [ -f $CREATE_DB ] && [ -f $CREATE_DB_TABLES ]; then
            echo "Se crea y configura la Base de datos"  >> $logFile
            cp $CREATE_DB /opt &>> $logFile
            cp $CREATE_DB_TABLES /opt &>> $logFile
            previousPath=`pwd`
            cd /opt
            su - postgres -c "psql -f /opt/${CREATE_DB}" &>> $logFile
            su - postgres -c "psql pegasusdatabase32 -f /opt/${CREATE_DB_TABLES}" &>> $logFile
            cd $previousPath
            # rm /opt/*.sql # @TODO: Cuando no haya problemas con la instalación, descomentar.
        fi
    fi
}
# -- fin de la función setupDataBas
```

Por lo que puedo ver el archivo de [log que genero](https://pastebin.com/LM01AViR) en el script, la función se ejecuta correctamente y los datos predefinidos se insertan correctamente.

Tras instalar Postgresql 9.4 y todo los demás programas que necesito así como configurarlo, reinicio el sistema.

Al intentar utilizar Postgresql la primera vez aparece este error:

```
psql: no se pudo conectar con el servidor: No existe el fichero o el directorio
    ¿Está el servidor en ejecución localmente y aceptando
    conexiones en el socket de dominio Unix «/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»?
```

La solución a este problema sé cual es. Simplemente tengo que ejecutar desde la terminal las siguientes líneas:

```
pg_dropcluster --stop 9.4 main
pg_createcluster --locale es_ES.UTF-8 9.4 main
service postgresql restart
```

He intentado ejecutar estas 3 líneas anteriores en el propio script de instalación pero no funciona.

Lo que quiero averiguar es **cómo** evitar este problema.

Supongo que el error está en que configuro los "locales" del sistema operativo y luego al instalar Postgresql no lo *pilla* bien. Quizás entre un paso y el otro haga falta un reinicio del sistema...

Para configurar los "locales" en el script uso la siguiente función:

```
##
## Función encargada de instalar y configuar la localización del sistema.
##
install_locales(){
    logFile=$1
    echo "Instalando 'locales'..." >> $logFile
    apt-get install locales -y &>> $logFile
    # locale-gen --purge en_US.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    echo "Configurando los locales a 'es_ES.UTF-8'" >> $logFile
    export LANGUAGE=es_ES
    export LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
    export LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8
    export LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8
    export LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8
    sed -i -e 's/# es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen
    locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninterative locales &>> $logFile
    echo "Se establecen algunas variables relacionadas con la localización..." >> $logFile
    update-locale LANGUAGE=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LANG=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_ALL=es_ES.UFT-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_CTYPE=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_MESSAGES=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    update-locale LC_COLLATE=es_ES.UTF-8 &>> $logFile
    echo "Resultado de la config. de los locales: " >> $logFile
    echo "······································" >> $logFile
    locale > /etc/locale.conf
    cat /etc/locale.conf &>> $logFile
    echo "······································" >> $logFile
    . /etc/default/locale
}
# -- fin de la función install_locale
```

Es cierto que en este [log](https://pastebin.com/4WdtTgjW) aparece un error. Pero cuando uso el sistema todo funciona en castellano correctamente, a excepción de Postgresql que directamente no funciona, y la verdad es que tampoco se cómo solucionarlo.

Desde ya muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y tiempo. Si necesitáis alguna otra información o duda, decirlo.

#### Edito 1

He probado a no cambiar la configuración de "locales". Sigue pasando exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: `He intentado ejecutar estas 3 líneas anteriores en el propio script de instalación pero no funciona.`. Qué es "no funciona" en este caso? Cuál es la salida de esos comandos?

Comment: Cuando ejecuto estas 3 líneas dentro de la función `setupDataBase`, no devuelven ningún error y devuelven la salida que se espera de ellas. Pero la BBDD sigue sin poderse utilizar. Sin embargo, tras toda la instalación, si ejecuto manualmente desde la terminal una a una estas 3 líneas me devuelven la misma salida y además ya puedo usar la BBDD sin problemas.

Comment: Creo que hasta que no reinicias no se levanta el servicio de postgres. Prueba a ejecutar los 3 comandos que comentas durante la instalación... pero justo antes levanta el servicio con el siguiente comando: `service postgresql start`